# gdalbuildvrt.exe doesn't recognize existing path

Tags: python, gdal, vrt

I used this function before but it suddenly stopped working on some updates. The simple command throws an error.

```
PS C:\> c:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin\gdalbuildvrt.exe 'c:/tmp/index.vrt' 'c:/tmp/*.tif'
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
ERROR 4: `c:/tmp/*.tif' does not exist in the file system, and is not recognized as a supported dataset name.
Warning 1: Can't open c:/tmp/*.tif. Skipping it
PS C:\>
```

I don't know what's wrong. The paths exist 100% and tif files are in it.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what is the exact reason for the issue but you are talking about this https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/1749. The Windows binaries from OSGeo4W should work.

Comment: Yes, this is my case, thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

Try leaving off the quotes on the second argument (path to the tifs). I'm using OSGeo windows binaries found here:[osgeo windows installer](https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/)

```
PS C:\> gdalbuildvrt 'C:/tmp/index.vrt' c:/tmp/*.tif
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not the case.

Comment: User30184 is correct, I am using the Windows binaries from OSGeo4W.